# Why isn't my while loop returning the correct values from a file?

Tags: java, loops, counter

I am trying to write a simple program to count the number of | pipes that occur in a line before a specific input value occurs in a Pipe Separated Value file.

I tried creating a while loop that goes through each character of the file and increments up 1 every time the value of FileInputStream.read() returns 124 (the Byte value for Pipe), but then resets to 0 if FileInputStream.read() returns 10 (the Byte value for New line) and increments the Line Counter + 1 instead.

```
while((filereader=fis.read())!=searchValue){

        int filereader = byteVal;
        if(byteVal == 10)
        {
            lineCt++;
            finalPipCT = 0;

        if(byteVal == 124)
        {
           pipeCtr++;
        }
        finalPipCT = finalPipCt + lineCt;
        System.out.println("Data: " + sippyStraw + "\t" + (char)sippyStraw);


  }
  System.out.println("Total | in line: "+ finalPipCT );
  System.out.println("Total lines til value: "+ lineCt );
}
```

If the text file was like this:

```
|a|b|c|

|d|e|f

|g|h|i|j|

|k|l|m||n|
```

and the searchValue was "h", I would expect it to return:

> Total | in line: 2
>   Total Lines til value: 3

The number of pipes that occur in the line from the start of said line before value h is matched.

Comment: You're not closing your first `if` correctly. Voted to close as typo.

Comment: Your code won't compile.  How did you test this?

Answer (score 0):

### This worked for me:

```
    String text = "|a|b|c|\n" + 
                "|d|e|f\n" + 
                "|g|h|i|j|";
    int lineCt = 1;
    int finalPipCT = 0;
    int searchVal = 104;

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length() && text.charAt(i) != 'h'; i++) {
    //while (scanner.hasNextByte() && (scanner.nextByte() != searchVal)) {
        int byteVal = (byte) text.charAt(i);

        if(byteVal == 10) {
                lineCt++;
                finalPipCT = 0;
        }

        if(byteVal == 124) {
            finalPipCT++;
        }   
    }

    System.out.println("Total | in line: "+ finalPipCT );
    System.out.println("Total lines til value: "+ lineCt );
```

---

I deleted some stuff, like 
"System.out.println("Data: " + sippyStraw + "\t" + (char)sippyStraw);"

And "finalPipCT = finalPipCt + lineCt;"

I also used a string instead of your file.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and informative answer. Would this same script work when using a BufferedReader on a txt file rather than a String?

Comment: I don't see why not. You would have to use a while loop rather than a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First some obvious issues:

- int filereader = byteVal; # is backwards
- missing ending statement bracket on first "if" statement.
- finalPipCT = finalPipCt + lineCt; # finalPipCt should be finalPipCT

A better solution would be to read the stream a line (BufferedReader) at a time and then parse though the characters in the line.  The reason is that you are making an assumption that the line-separator is 10.  For Windows files it is different.  If you use the buffered reader to read a line then the EOL is handled for you.

Your while loop should read lines until the value is null.  Your code will attempt to read a byte even after the end of the file (if it never finds the search byte).